# How can I delay a plugin execution from a callback?

Tags: jquery

I've written a lightweight jquery plugin to manage tab switching, it's worked well in development and testing. I've had an odd requirement for one of the tabs to expand in height on opening and then contract the height on closing. The changes are required to be an animation, the opening is easily done using a callback that fires when the tab switching is complete.

I can't however get the closing animation to work, this is due to the plugin continuing and hiding the tab before the animation is complete.

Is there anyway I can force the plugin to pause until a callback function is complete?

The code I'm using to fire the callback is

```
if($.isFunction(params.click)){
    params.click.apply(this,[content,tab,set]);
};
```

I don't really want to go down the road of managing animations in the plugin

Comment: Can you not send a callback to the original callback ?

Comment: I had thought of that but my company might start to use this plugin in more places, the way it's written the majority of the plugin would be in the callback, I'm not sure that's really how I want to handle it, but if all else fails it's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you plugin knows which tab is currently "open" then the opening of a new tab is happening at the same time as the closing of another tab.

Thus if you have the power to call a callback function provided by the client code, for the opening of a new tab, you would surely need to call a "closing" callback on the previously open tab?

Comment: yes, but in that closing callback the client code is running an animation, as that runs the plugin hides the currently open tab, along with the running animation. Because the animation in instantiated in the client code I can't use the normal jquery.animate complete call back to stop the plugin from running what i essentially want to do is run the closing callback in a synchronous manner, ie the plugin pauses until the callback is complete

Comment: You should never have an actual pause, for usability reasons it would be a terrible idea; and to half answer the original question, there is no API for pausing the execution of a plugin in jQuery. I would recommend that you have callbacks `tabClosing` and `tabOpening` which would both be fired at the same time when a user selects a new tab. I will update by answer with how you could use that to create the effect your after.

Answer (score 0):

Create a callback for both the opening and closing of tabs, such that whenever a user changes the tab the `tabOpening` event is fired for the new tab, and the `tabClosing` event is called for the old tab.

Be specific in your documentation as to which will occur first to make using your plugin easy! Assuming that `tabClosing` would fire first you could then write client code as follows:

```
var $closingTab = null,
    $openingTab = null;

$('#target').yourPlugin({
    tabClosing: function(tab) {
        $closingTab = $(tab);
    },
    tabOpening: function(tab) {
        $openingTab = $(tab);
        // Animate the 
        $closingTab.animate({}, 1000, function() {
            $openingTab.animate({}, 1000);
        });
    }
});
```

Or more simply, but less primitively you could have a `tabChange` callback which could ecapsulate the whole event:

```
$('#target').yourPlugin({
    tabChange: function(oldTab, newTab) {
        $(oldTab).animate({}, 1000, function() {
            $(newTab).animate({}, 1000);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: First off thanks for the replies, when I said the plugin was light weight i really did mean it. if I do as you have described above a lot of the plugin will be redundant. I'm starting to think that this code just needs adding to the main script file for the site.